# gcc doesn't want to use AVX on mac

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-mountain-lion, avx

So I have this brand new mac book pro with intel core I7 processor and `sysctl machdep.cpu.features` giving

machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 xAPIC POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE TSCTMR AVX1.0 RDRAND F16C

yet when I run gcc (4.7.2 macports), it doesn't #define `__AVX__`. What's wrong? (Mac OS X 10.8.2)

Comment: Use clang that comes with Xcode - this supports AVX.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257375/does-xcode-4-have-support-for-avx/5264405#5264405

Comment: Use clang. It supports AVX and it does support C++11.

Comment: @VladLazarenko `clang` also doesn't define `__AVX__`

Comment: @Walter: Apple's clang certainly *does* define `__AVX__`, e.g. `clang -dM -E -mavx - < /dev/null | grep -i avx` produces `#define __AVX__ 1`

Comment: You need to state the compiler flags you are using, otherwise an answer will be guesswork

Comment: What C++11 features do you need that clang doesn't have?

Comment: @StephenCanon Not only do I need C++11, but also openMP (which clang doesn't support at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I depends on the compiler flags you are using wether `__AVX__` and `__SSEx__` will be defined.

So if you are using `g++ -march=corei7avx` the macro will be defined. `-march=native` should also suffice, if gcc is able to detect you cpu correctly (it usually is).

Comment: thanks. yes, with `march=native` it picks them up. `march=corei7avx` is not recognised ('bad valud for -march= switch'). However, when I use `march=native`, gcc still cannot produce a useful output, since the linker cannot deal with the avx instructions. This is the cctools linker that comes with macports. I read on some other question some work around, but wonder whether I can simple tell gcc to use another linker? Where would I find the binutils (g)as? I installed it (macports) but cannot find gas.

Answer (score 0):

On my i7 MBP 13" (mid 2010) running 10.6.8, the current MacPorts gcc 4.7.3 and 4.8.2 do define **AVX** when -mavx is specified. They however crash compiling code using boost::simd (available via www.metascale.org).
Macports clang-3.3 has no such issues, but takes way longer to compile (with or without -mavx, compared to gcc >= 4.7 WITHOUT -mavx).